# How is this expression simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this:

$$\sqrt{(dx)^2 + (dy)^2}$$

And my book simplified it as:

$$\sqrt{1 + \Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2} \times dx$$

I don't have even a close idea how he did it. If it helps, is about path lenght whit integration.

Comment: Your last differential in the second part should be *outside* the radical, not inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a\sqrt{r} = \sqrt{a^2(r)}\quad\text{if }a\gt 0\text{ and } r\gt 0.$$
So, using changes instead of differentials:
$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)^2} \Delta x &= \sqrt{\left(\Delta x\right)^2\left(1 + \left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)^2\right)}\\
&= \sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2}.
\end{align*}$$
Taking limits as $\Delta x\to 0$ converts $\Delta x$ to $dx$, $\Delta y$ to $dy$, and $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}$ to the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: Hooo thank you :) I didn't know the first rule :) Yeah, I used dy because I don't know how to put Δ.

Comment: @Andres: The first rule is just a consequence of two things: (i) if $a$ and $b$ are both positive, then $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$; and (ii) $\sqrt{r^2} = |r|$. Putting them both together, if $a$ and $b$ are positive, then $a\sqrt{b} = $\sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a^2b}$.

Comment: Thank you :) Where you learn that kind of things ? I am at first year in University. Not EEUU, Argentina :)

Comment: @Andres This is standard root manipulation, which I believe is taught in second or third year in high school in Argentina.

Comment: talmid, I live in Argentina, high school education is very poor -.-, that's why I am getting problems at University whit this kind of things :/

Comment: I still can't understand, if I have $$\sqrt{(Δx)^2 + (Δy)^2}$$ isn't it the same as ? $$\sqrt{1^2 \times (Δx)^2 + (Δy)^2}$$ ? Can't understand why there is (1 + ...)

Comment: @Andres: I don't understand your question. Yes, the two expressions you have are the same. And $1^2$ is the same as $1$. So? You are just using basic algebra: $a+b = a(1+\frac{b}{a})$.

Comment: @Andres That's the same, you're forgetting the part about the common factor $\Delta x$: $a+b = 1 \times a + \frac{b}{a} \times a = (1 + \frac{b}{a}) \times a$.

Comment: I think I need some basic Math book for that kind of things :/

Comment: @Andres I suggest http://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/exponents-radicals, for example. Or pick any third-year high school math book. Properties and tricks of algebraic manipulation like these are ubiquitous in higher-level courses, and people often use them without pointing out what they are doing, like in this case.

Comment: Such stupid... It is simply common factor and everything is clear :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \sqrt{(dx)^2 + (dy)^2} = \sqrt{\left(1 + \frac{(dy)^2}{(dx)^2}\right)\cdot(dx)^2} = \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \cdot \sqrt{(dx)^2}= \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\cdot dx$

(Note that we're treating $dx$ and $dy$ as numbers, but that's another issue; see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-dy-dx-not-a-ratio).)

Comment: It helps if you think about the Pythagorean theorem, first, noting how a right triangle (with legs $dx$ and $dy$) has its hypoteneuse be $\sqrt{(dx)^{2}+(dy)^{2}}$; we want to change this expression into a differential, i.e., something that looks like $f(x)\,dx$. We can do this using the algebraic manipulations shown in this answer...

Comment: Thank you talmid :) Like I said in the other answer i didn't know the rule: $$a \times \sqrt{r+s} = \sqrt{a^2 \times (r+s)}$$

Comment: @Andres Yes, because (assuming $a \geq 0$) $\sqrt{a^2(r+s)} = \sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{r+s} = a \sqrt{r+s}$.